# "Prepare your Menora before Shabbat!"

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia, motzei-shabbos, erev-shabbat

In [this](http://halocho.blogspot.com/2012/12/halocho-998-shabbat-erev-chanuka.html) recent "Halocho a Day" blog post, [Danny Schoemann](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/501/danny-schoemann) leads off with

> This week, Shabbat is also Erev Chanuka; prepare your Menora before Shabbat!

This sounds like a nice idea for reducing the scramble after Shabbat and demonstrating affection for a mitzva. Is it just good advice from a blogger, or is it recommended/required by halachic sources?

Comment: And furthermore, is this something that should be emphasized even if one forgot (neglected) to do so by Friday morning and is out all day Friday (like at work), if it will then create an additional scramble _before_ Shabbath? ('Cuz I've never heard of it till now, so...whoops!)

Comment: @SethJ Good point. Yeah, sorry: I'd never heard of this tactic before either, and if my public-minded instincts were a tad stronger, I'd've posted this question last night *before* I set up the family's chanukiyot.

Comment: No worries.[15]

Comment: As @Gershon-Gold pointed out, it's not Halacha. It's merely good advice. In the original draft this "heading" was a footnote, making it obvious it had no Halachic source. I'm going to edit the post and preface that line with "Suggestion" (so that the mistake doesn't get perpetuated when I copy it next year). Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 7):

Although it does not list a source - [Luach Davar Be'ito](http://www.hamodia.com/inthepaper.cfm?ArticleID=388) says ([29 Kislev 5755](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50871&st=&pgnum=457&hilite=)):

> המדקדקים מכינים כבר עתה את פתילות נרות החנוכה שלמחרת ליל
>       מוצש׳׳ק, למען ימצאון מוכנות בבואם מחר מביהכ׳׳נ ויהיו זריזים מקדימים.‏
>
> Those that are careful prepare before Shabbos the Chanuka candles in order to light as soon as possible after Shabbos.

*(abridged translation mine)*

Comment: Believe it or not, I'd never heard of this fascinating project or author before. Thanks very much for bringing it up!